# Can Docker Swarm be ran on a single machine?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is it possible to have the simplest architecture of Docker Swarm where a single server is both the manager and the worker? That is, every application is being ran on the manager's instance.

Comment: It is, yes! By default the Swarm manager is also a worker node.

Comment: Thank you (should I delete my question or leave it?)

Comment: It's a fairly brief question, but since it is on-topic and clear, you can delete it or leave it as you choose.

Comment: You may incidentally be interested in a small Swarm demo I wrote: https://github.com/halfer/cd-demo-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use docker swarm with a single node, but I recommend you use the docker-compose.

`docker swarm init`

Comment: Why is `docker-compose` better in this case? I think there are benefits to using single node stacks over `docker-compose`. Specifically that you can apply CPU/memory limits to individual containers